# How to use Oat++ with OpenSSL instead of LibreSSL?

Tags: openssl, oat++

For various reasons, LibreSSL is not an option here.

What do I need to do to use Oat++ with OpenSSL instead? I have OpenSSL-1.1.1h installed system-wide.

Comment: The simplest way would be to wait for the oatpp-openssl adaptor. Taking into account the rising number of requests we'll have to implement it in the nearest future.

Comment: Also, if you are familiar with OpenSSL, you can hack a Connection Provider for Oat++.

Comment: Sorry, I am extremely unfamiliar with Oat++. And while I have some familiarity with OpenSSL, it may not be enough to write a Connection Provider for it. :-(

Answer (score 3):

The new [OpenSSL adaptor](https://github.com/oatpp/oatpp-openssl) was added in the recent release [1.2.5](https://github.com/oatpp/oatpp/blob/master/changelog/1.2.5.md).

Now, to use oatpp with OpenSSL all you have to do is:

- Install `oatpp-openssl`.
- Use oatpp-openssl connection providers as described in the [readme](https://github.com/oatpp/oatpp-openssl/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: Thank you! Installed `oatpp-openssl`, and it worked like a charm.